# How to Get Value from TextBox in to Controller Method MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, textbox

I have the following MVC view to invite users to register to my site

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Tools", FormMethod.Post,
            new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <h2>Invite Users</h2>
            <p class="text-info">@ViewBag.StatusMessage</p>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmailAddress, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress, 
                        new { @class = "form-control", id = "email" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Access To", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("Product", new SelectList(
                        new List<Object> {
                            new { Text = "Product1", Value = "Product1" },
                            new { Text = "Product2", Value = "Product2" },
                            new { Text = "All", Value = "All" }},
                            "Value",
                            "Text"),
                            new { @class = "form-control", id = "product" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="button" value="Invite User" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

This view has three tab pages, this is the first of three tabs. The ViewModel for this is view is

```
public class AdministratorViewModel
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public List<Download> Uploads { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationUser> UserList { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following JavaScript to pass the required fields back to the controller

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("input[type=button]").click(function () {
            var data_email = $('#email').text();
            var data_product = $('#product option:selected').text();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Tools/SendInvite',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { email: data_email, product: data_product },
                success: function (result) {
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The controller method is

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> SendInvite(
    string email, string product)
{
    ApplicationUser user = null;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        if (user.IsAdmin != null && (bool)user.IsAdmin)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tools");
}
```

This method is fired, and `product` is correct and contains the selected value. However, the `email` is always empty.

**Why is email always empty and how can I pass email to my controller?**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try to replace $('#email').text() with $('#email').val()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.val()` method to get the actual value of the textbox element using jQuery.

example:

```
var data_email = $('#email').val();
```

try and let me know if this has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`var data_email = $('#email').text();` this should be null.
Try `console.log(data_email)` below this line and you will see.

You can get the value of an input field

like this: `var data_email = $('#email').val();`

or like this: `var data_email = $('#email').attr('value');`

Comment: Thanks very much for your time. You were 30 seconds slower than Mohammed, so I have accepted his answer...